# Switching between jTabbedPane within a jTabbedPane

Tags: java, applet, japplet

I am creating an Applet on which has multiple tabs, but I have hit a wall.
I know that Applet.setSelectedIndex(1); will change tabs between Lesson 1 & Lesson 2 and so on but is there a way I can change tabs between Lesson 1.1-1.5 with a button as Applet.setSelectedIndex(TAB NUMBER); doesn't work?

EDIT: SOLVED WITH THIS:

```
 private void Lesson11To12MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
        Applet.setSelectedIndex(/*Whatever index*/);
        Lesson2TabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(/*Whatever index*/);
    }
```

Thank you in advance :) Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9QWZ.png

Mark Lang.

Comment: `jTabbedPane.getModel().setSelectedIndex(n)`. The model being a SingleSelectionModel.

Comment: This still doesn't help switch between Lesson 1.1-1.5... It still does Lesson 1 to 2 and so on

Comment: It is a JTabbedPane with an other JTabbedPane inside. The inner JTabbedPane must be taken. So look in the source code.

Comment: It is a JTabbedPane, with a JPanel inside of it, because if I added in a JTabbedPane to the Lesson1.1 it would make a tab within a tab within a tab, which is not what I want.

Comment: Nevertheless you'll need the JTabbedPane object with riders to the left.

Comment: Variable Names for the tabs you see from the image:
 IntroTab, Lesson1TabbedPane, Lesson2TabbedPane etc, within each tab is: Lesson1Point1, Lesson1Point2, Lesson1Point3, Lesson1Point4, Lesson1Point5.. (Lesson2Point1 and so on)

Comment: Momentarily there are shown two JTabbedPanes: with riders at the top and one with riders to the left. The latter is where you select 1.1 - 1.5.

Comment: I do not see what you are mentioning, I shall link all of my tabs/Applet panes: https://imgur.com/nXL6zvr